# Call function from parent (using new)

Tags: javascript

I have a have a class `Kid` which I use to create a new object in `Manager` using `this.kid = new Kid()`. Then from the kid I want to call a function from `Manager` ( `doSomething()` ), is this possible? I tried using `super()` but it does not work because is a non derived constructor. How can I do this?

Manager:

```
'use strict';

import Kid from './Kid';

export default class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }


  init() {
    this.kid = new Kid();
  }

  doSomething(someInput) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

Kid class:

```
'use strict';

export default class Kid {
  constructor() {
    // call parent doSomething()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your parent to the constructor for `Kid`. Save it off and call it.

'use strict';

import Kid from './Kid';

```
export default class Manager {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }


  init() {
    this.kid = new Kid(this);
  }

  doSomething(someInput) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}


export default class Kid {
  constructor(parent) {
    parent.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid because that was super easy haha, thank you! I mark as solved when I can after 10 min